# libgnuutils memory leak when threading

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I'm doing some threading and I've been getting this memory leak. 
The threads run through then join at the end. I'm new to threading so I don't really know what the library error is shown by Valgrind is, so any help would be appreciated. I don't get the Valgrind errors every time I run them, just with large amounts of threads.

````
==38009==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==38009==    by 0x7904736: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.5)
==38009==    by 0x7905C79: asn1_array2tree (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.5)
==38009==    by 0x61B5C24: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10)
==38009==    by 0x6194590: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10)
==38009==    by 0x4010732: call_init (dl-init.c:72)
==38009==    by 0x4010732: _dl_init (dl-init.c:119)
==38009==    by 0x40010C9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so)
==38009==    by 0x4: ???
==38009==    by 0x1FFF00027A: ???
==38009==    by 0x1FFF000286: ???
==38009==    by 0x1FFF0002A7: ???
==38009==    by 0x1FFF0002AC: ???```


    for (i=0; i<threads; i++) {
                    if((pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL,threader,(void *)param))!=0){
                            printf("failed to make thread\n");
                    }
                    else{
                    printf("made thread\n");
                    }
            }
            int j;
            for (j=0; j<threads; j++) {
            if((pthread_join(thread[j],NULL))!=0){
                    printf("failed to join thread\n");
                    }
                    else{printf("joined thread\n");}
            }
````

Comment: If you want help identifying the problem you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And enabling debugging info in your build will give you more meaningful back traces.

Comment: Valgrind will catch many memory leak problems in the C library functions.  However, that is something you cannot correct.  Therefore, you should tell Valgrind to ignore memory leaks in C library function.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding:  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level if 4 spaces (not tabs)

Comment: How exactly would I go about telling Valgrind to ignore leaks in C library function?